# array element in z3 counterexample

Tags: z3, smt

counterexample output of an aaary element of z3 tool

I try the following python code, and get an counterexample

```
from z3 import Solver, parse_smt2_string
s = Solver()
#str1="(declare-const x Int) (declare-const y Int) (declare-const z Int) (declare-const a1 (Array Int Int)) (declare-const a2 (Array Int Int)) (declare-const a3 (Array Int Int))  (assert (= (select a1 x) x)) (assert (= (store a1 x y) a1))"
str1="(define-sort A () (Array Int Int Int)) (define-fun bag-union ((x A) (y A)) A   ((_ map (+ (Int Int) Int)) x y)) (declare-const s1 A) (declare-const s2 A) (declare-const s3 A) (assert (= s3 (bag-union s1 s2))) (assert (= (select s1 0 0) 5)) (assert (= (select s2 0 0) 3)) (assert (= (select s2 1 2) 4))"
s.add(parse_smt2_string(str1))
s.check()
m = s.model()    
for d in m:     
  print(d,m[d])
if str(s.check())=="sat":  
    print(s.model())  
    m = s.model()    
    for d in m: 
        print(d,m[d])


(s2, [(1, 2) -> 4, (0, 0) -> 3, else -> 7719])
(s3, [(1, 2) -> 8859, (0, 0) -> 8, else -> 8955])
(s1, [(1, 2) -> 8855, (0, 0) -> 5, else -> 1236])
(k!1, [(1, 2) -> 4, (0, 0) -> 3, else -> 7719])
(k!2, [(1, 2) -> 8859, (0, 0) -> 8, else -> 8955])
(k!0, [(1, 2) -> 8855, (0, 0) -> 5, else -> 1236])
....
```

The lines such as (k!1, [(1, 2) -> 4, (0, 0) -> 3, else -> 7719]) confuse me? 
They seem duplicate lines (s2, [(1, 2) -> 4, (0, 0) -> 3, else -> 7719.
Can I add an option not to show these lines?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing SMTLib and Python inputs into one; there's really no good reason to do this. Either program in Python, or in SMTLib. When you use z3 this way, you have no access to the variables you have defined. If you directly program in z3py, then you can simply query the values of the variables you have defined with ease. Other than that, your best bet is to simply check if the name is of the form `k!n` and skip it inside your `for` loop.

Also note that what will be printed in the output for these "auxiliary" model variables is quite z3 version dependent. When I run your program with the latest version of z3 from github sources, it prints:

```
(s2, Store(K(Int, 4), 0, 0, 3))
(s1, K(Int, 5))
(s3, Store(K(Int, 9), 0, 0, 8))
[s2 = Store(K(Int, 4), 0, 0, 3),
 s1 = K(Int, 5),
 s3 = Store(K(Int, 9), 0, 0, 8)]
(s2, Store(K(Int, 4), 0, 0, 3))
(s1, K(Int, 5))
(s3, Store(K(Int, 9), 0, 0, 8))
```

which has no mention of `k!n` variables. Mixing the two input languages this way is merely asking for a lot of confusion.

Comment: thanks, if I prefer using the SMTLib format input, and I also want to return the counterexample for further refinement guidline, I just use the command:m = s.model(), then

Comment: Sure.. But then you've no control over keeping track of what your variables were. The whole point of programming in Python (or in a higher-level API than SMTLib) is so that you *can* keep track of your variables and do further programming with them.